# create new folder structure within FTP Account

Tags: command-line, scripts, directory, ftp, vsftpd

I am working on project where i need to create this kind of Folder structure with FTP Account. I just have FTP account detail and no access to the server,

I can connect with FTP and can create directory manually but i need to create such a folder structure within ftp root directory.

```
    YYYY
    |_MM
    |_DD

2018
|_06
 |_01
 |_02
 |_03
 |_..............30
|_07
 |_01
 |_02
 |_03
 |_..............31
```

please advice what will be the best approach to finish it without manually creation of folder.

> **EDITED After some hint from comments/**

I wrote this script to create the folder structure but the date concept didnt work with my scripts.

```
#/bin/bash
for i in $(seq -w 12)
do  
    cd /home/user/upload/2018/
    mkdir $i
    cd $i
    for j in $(seq -w 31)
    do 
        mkdir $j
    done
done
```

Comment: You could create such structure locally using `bash` and push it to the `ftp` server with `mput` command.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, thanks that will be good approach, I will try to write such a bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `bash` script will create a directory structure you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

year=2018

mkdir "$year"

for month in {6..12}
do
    mkdir "$year"/"$month"
    days=$(cal "$month" "$year" | awk 'NF {DAYS = $NF}; END {print DAYS}')

    for ((i=1; i <= days; i++))
    do
    mkdir "$year"/"$month"/"$(printf "%02d\n" "$i")"
    done
done
```

Use `tree` to see how the structure looks like:

```
$ tree 2018
2018
├── 10
│   ├── 01
│   ├── 02
│   ├── 03
│   ├── 04
│   ├── 05
│   ├── 06
│   ├── 07
│   ├── 08
│   ├── 09
│   ├── 10
│   ├── 11
│   ├── 12
│   ├── 13
│   ├── 14
│   ├── 15
│   ├── 16
│   ├── 17
│   ├── 18
│   ├── 19
│   ├── 20
│   ├── 21
│   ├── 22
│   ├── 23
│   ├── 24
│   ├── 25
│   ├── 26
│   ├── 27
│   ├── 28
│   ├── 29
│   ├── 30
│   └── 31
├── 11
│   ├── 01
│   ├── 02
(...)
```

The method for checking how many days are in a given month comes [from
here](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2013/03/24/how-to-get-number-of-days-in-a-month-using-shell-commands/).

Comment: The inner for next can be 1 mkdir command. All you need is the end day number of a month and do `mkdir {01:endday}` and it will make 01 through 31 if 31 days.

Comment: @Rinzwind: `mkdir {01:31}` creates `{01:31}` directory, I use `GNU bash, version 4.3.46`. I thought about using `mkdir {01..$days}` but `shellcheck` says: `SC2051: Bash doesn't support variables in brace range expansions.`

Comment: new_fol.sh: 13: new_fol.sh: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
error comes at this line     `    for ((i=1; i <= days; i++))
`

Comment: I don't get this error, what is your `bash` version?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk `bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.`

Comment: Also make sure that you use `bash` and not `dash`. When `dash` is used `Bad for loop variable` is indeed shown, therefore I have used `bash` explicitly in `shebang`.

Comment: @i am using excatly the same script but bad for loop variable comes up

Comment: I see that you named the script `new_fol.sh` - what if you run it like this: `bash new_fol.sh`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk GNU bash, version 4.3.11  -> `cd /tmp/ && mkdir test && cd test &&  mkdir {01..31} && ls` ->  `01  03  05  07  09  11  13  15  17  19  21  23  25  27  29  31 02  04  06  08  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24  26  28  30`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, it works if i run the script like this_: `bash new_fol.sh`

Comment: @Rinzwind: I know about [`sequence expressions`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), notice that I've also used them in my script. You mentioned `mkdir {01:endday}` which doesn't work for me even with `Bash 4.4.19` I've just built form `git`.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `date`, you could do it by incrementing the date directly and using path separators in the format e.g.

```
d='2018/06/01'
while [ "$d" != "2018/12/31" ]; do 
  mkdir -p "$d"
  d="$(date '+%Y/%m/%d' -d "$d + 1 day")"
done
```

Choose the start date and end date (inside the `while` condition) appropriately.